# How to find visual studio 2022 Performance profiler problem to work?

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, performancecounter

Installed Visual studio 2022 Enterprise (17.06) on my machine(Windows 10). Want to run the Performance profiler on my .NET6 web application.

In Release mode, when I chose Debug>Performance profiler, it start to work and run/open the website in the browser but stay at this state and stop working at collection data, as you can see in the photo, and not working anymore.

[image]

When I click on the stop button shows me this error:

**Microsoft Visual Studio was unable to create a diagnosis report. Check output window for errors.**

On the output windows:

**The diagnostics session stopped with errors.
File not found: 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\Report.CC361609-8704-4840-B03F-7349937A6E25'.**

What I did to solve it:

- Checked that path, there is no file with this name: "Report.CC361609-8704-4840-B03F-7349937A6E25"
- Restart Computer
- Delete .vs folder
- Rebuild and create the project
- Check Windows Events Log, There is nothing about this

But doesn't fix it, is there a log file or something to find the problem?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Diagnostics-session-stopped-with-errors/1390399

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? I found the issue in VS 2022 (version 17.3.4)

Comment: @Md.FaisalHabib no ,I didn't work on this issue anymore